# Function that can take arrays with different dimensions

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector

Is there a method to create a single function that can take any dimension of vector without overloading?

Currently I have,

```
someFunction(vector<int> a)
someFunction(vector<vector<int> > a)
someFunction(vector<vector<vector<int> > > a)
```

However, would it be possible to have a function:

```
singleFunction(<n-dimension vector>)
{
    // Get dimension of array/vector
}
```

Comment: Make a template?

Comment: Just template on `vector<T>`.

Comment: What do you do inside that function?

Comment: Let's take a step back here: `vector<T>`: a list of stuff, useful thing, no further questions. `vector<vector<int>>`: a list of lists; already earns you a raised eyebrow. Are you sure that's the right data structure? For even further nesting, I'm really reluctant to believe that's the right way to attack whatever problem you actually have.

Comment: Is the "dimension" of a `vector<vector<int> >` equal to `2`, or is it related to the actual size of one of the vectors or contained vectors?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a recursive template function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void func(int el) {
  std::cout << el << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void func(std::vector<T> v) {
  for (const T& el : v) {
    func(el);
  }
}

int main() {
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> v {{1, 2}, {2, 3}};
  func(v);
  return 0;
}
```

It's calling it itself for each element until it reaches elements of type int.

To get the dimension you can use the same pattern:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
int someFunction(std::vector<T> v, int dim = 1);

template<>
int someFunction(std::vector<int> v, int dim) {
  return dim;
}

template<typename T>
int someFunction(std::vector<T> v, int dim) {
  return someFunction(T(), dim + 1);
}

template<typename T>
void singleFunction(std::vector<T> v) {
  int dim(someFunction(v));
  std::cout << dim << std::endl;
  // Do something
}

int main() {
  std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> v {{{1, 0}, {2, 4}}, {{2, 2}, {3, 0}}};
  singleFunction(v);
  singleFunction(std::vector<std::vector<int>>());
  singleFunction(std::vector<int>());
  return 0;
}
```

Here it creates a new object of value type and calls itself until its value type is int. Every time it increments the dimension.

Comment: This is a smart solution to iterate through all the elements. But you do not get the "dimension" for which OP asks.
Anyway, I completely agree with @Baum mit Augen comment: that is a very suspicious data structure.

Comment: Although the template overloads the non-template func. So not quite what was asked.

Comment: I fixed it. Better?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could try this approach, I think this is exactly what you are asking (adopted from [std::rank](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/rank)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct vector_rank : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> {};

template<typename T>
struct vector_rank<std::vector<T>> : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, vector_rank<T>::value + 1> {};

template<typename T>
size_t GetVectorRank(T)
{
    return vector_rank<T>::value;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>>> v1;
    std::cout << GetVectorRank(v1) << std::endl;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> v2;
    std::cout << GetVectorRank(v2) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The second template be selected recursively while the type is `std::vector<T>`,  the first template will be selected for everything else as well as at the end of recursion. The above example will return:

```
5
3
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/CLucGA

Comment: Good catch! But it would be a much better answer if you explained that it works because the second template is *more specialized* that the first one for a vector or vector so it will be selected until you reach a simple vector for which only first template applies.

Comment: @SergeBallesta added some explanation, thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 2):

With `C++17` you can write a pretty simple solution:

```
template<typename T >
constexpr int func(){
  if constexpr (is_vector<typename T::value_type>::value )
   return 1+func<typename T::value_type>();
  return 1;
}

int main() {
    cout<< func<vector<vector<vector<vector<vector<int>>>>>>() <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

which return `5` as expected.

You need to define `is_vector` as follows:

```
template<class T>
struct is_vector{
     static bool const value = false;   
};
template<class T>
struct is_vector<std::vector<T> > {
  static bool const value = true;
};
```

Comment: c++17 is almost cheating

Answer (score 1):

A simple template should solve this. From memory:

```
template <T> singleFunction(vector<T> &t) {
    return t.size();
}
```

Comment: This will return the number of elements in `t`, not the "dimension" i.e. the number of nested vectors.

Comment: If the nestedness is needed then I like the answere by Killzone Kid

Answer (score 1):

you can get the dimension with this code

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<unsigned N, typename T>
struct meta {
    static unsigned func() {//terminale recursion case
        return N;
    }
};

template<unsigned N, typename T>
struct meta<N, std::vector<T> > {//mid recursion case
    static unsigned func() {
        return meta<N + 1, T>::func();
    }
};

template<typename T>
unsigned func(T) { //adapter to deduce the type
    return meta<0, T>::func();
}

int main() {
  std::cout << func(std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int> > >()) << std::endl;
  std::cout << func(std::vector<int>()) << std::endl;
  std::cout << func(int()) << std::endl;
  std::cout << func(std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int> > > > > >()) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

will output

```
3
1
0
6
```